# File/Folder encryption per process on Linux

Tags: security, encryption, permissions, filesystems

Let's say I'm running some application on a linux box, and I need to give it access to an encrypted file/folder. I could use something like encfs, but in that case when I decrypt the file it becomes visible to the whole system, all processes can read it, is that right? Is it possible to decrypt a file/folder only for a single process?

Comment: "For a single process" is not a very good security model (it could fork, change uid etc...), but you could mount the filesystem somewhere like `/mnt/special_user/my_encrypted_fs` and make `/mnt/special_user` be owned by `special_user:special_user` with permissions `0100`.

Comment: Hey @root thanks. Could you elaborate a little more on this, I don't quite understand. Would I need to run each application as a dedicated user to achieve this?

Comment: You'd need to run as the user who is allowed to access the decrypted data, i.e. the user who owns that single process you want to run.